# excel vba inputbox that can accept numbers, special characters etc

Tags: excel, insert, user-input, inputbox, vba

I have a set of inputs that need to be set by the user before the macro will run. The inputs are stored in various cells that are called out later on in the macro. The inputs will be some assortment of either numbers, words, or punctuation (ex:  . - , *). When ever I put a "." into the input box the code stops and highlights the inputbox code. Is there something ( if statement, different type on input box) that can handle basically anything that gets thrown at it?

```
Dim AN As Range
Dim AO As Range
Dim AP As Range

    Set AN = Application.InputBox(PROMPT:="ENTER SEPERATOR AFTER BLOCK/ARRAY NUMBER", Type:=2)
    Range("AN4") = AN
    Set AO = Application.InputBox(PROMPT:="ENTER SEPERATOR AFTER INVERTER NUMBER", Type:=2)
    Range("AO4") = AO
    Set AP = Application.InputBox(PROMPT:="ENTER SEPERATOR AFTER COMBINERBOX NUMBER", Type:=2)
    Range("AP4") = AP
```

Comment: instead of using InputBox, how about have the user enter the information right into a set of cells before running the code. Almost like setting up a form on the datasheet itself?

Comment: Ah - I see you set your variables a type `Range`, then try to assign them to a type `String` inputbox value. If you set your variables to type `String` your code should work as is. Also, once you change them to type `String` remove the `Set` in front of each InputBox line.

Comment: Thanks for that. I copied the code from a different input box that was a range I just forgot to adjust. When I have more time, I plan on fooling around with a userform that contains all the inputs needed for the entire macro

Answer (score 1):

change yours to the following, works ok for me:

```
Set AN = Range("A4")
AN.Value = Application.InputBox(PROMPT:="ENTER SEPERATOR AFTER BLOCK/ARRAY NUMBER", Type:=2)
```